# cordova push notification plugin throws error

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

On adding PushNotification plugin to my cordova project (i.e. cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git) is throwing error. I read that there are some issues with plugin. So how can I implement the push notifications with cordova. I found this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pushnotification-parsepushnotification But there is no method to trigger on notification received. How to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Telerik Push Notifications Plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/PushNotification), it is based on the Phonegap Push Plugin.You can find the [documentation here.](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/javascript/push-notifications/push-getting-started)

*EDIT*

Since you want to use the cordova plugin itself, you can try this workaround
install a previous version of the same  plugin and check whether its working for you

for that you can navigate to this [link,](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/releases/1.5.2)download the source and then istall it locally via the command

```
cordova plugin add *Location of the Locally downloaded plugin*
```

Comment: I want to use cordova plugin itself and not telerik.

Comment: Thanks. This version works. But still waiting for latest version to update